# Accurate AWK array searching

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

Can anybody offer some help getting this AWK to search correctly?

I need to search inside the "sample.txt" file for all the 6 array elements in the "combinations" file. However, I need the search to happen from every single character instead of like an ordinary text editor search box type search, which searches by blocks after each occurrence. I need to search in the most squeezed in way so as to display exactly every times it happens. For example I need the type of search that finds inside the string "AAAAA" the combination "AAA" happening 3 times, not 1 time. See my previous post about this: [BASH: Search a string and exactly display the exact number of times a substring happens inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053094/bash-search-a-string-and-exactly-display-the-exact-number-of-times-a-substring)

The sample.txt file is:

```
AAAAAHHHAAHH
```

The combinations file is:

```
AA  
HH  
AAA  
HHH  
AAH  
HHA
```

How do I get the script

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'NR==FNR {data=$0; next} {printf "%s %d \n",$1,gsub($1,$1,data)}' 'sample.txt' combinations > searchoutput
```

to output the desired output:

```
AA 5
HH 3
AAA 3
HHH 1
AAH 2
HHA 1
```

instead of what it is currently outputing:

```
AA 3 
HH 2 
AAA 1 
HHH 1 
AAH 2 
HHA 1
```

?

As we can see, the script is only finding the combinations just like a text editor. I need it to search for the combinations from the start of every character instead so that the desired output happens.

How do I have the AWK output the desired output instead? Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there may be a faster way to find the first match and carry forward from that index, but this might be simpler

```
$ awk 'NR==1{content=$0;next} 
            {c=0; len1=length($1); 
             for(i=1;i<=length(content)-len1+1;i++)
                c+=substr(content,i,len1)==$1;
             print $1,c}' file combs

AA 5
HH 3
AAA 3
HHH 1
AAH 2
HHA 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try this:

```
$ awk '{x="AAAAAHHHAAHH"; n=0}{
    while(t=index(x,$0)){n++; x=substr(x,t+1) } 
    print $0,n
}' combinations.txt 
AA 5
HH 3
AAA 3
HHH 1
AAH 2
HHA 1
```