# Display how array elements are found in data file?

Tags: bash, awk

Hello and thanks for reading my post, I really appreciate it.

Need a way to read from the arrayfile and search the datafile in a way that prints out how the arrayfile elements are found. An awk one liner is preferred.

arrayfile:

```
haha
hahh
```

datafile:

```
aaahahahaaaahahahhaaahahahaaahahaaaa
```

desiredoutputfile:

```
haha 1110111
hahh 0001000
```

So its basically remove the last character from the arrayfile elements, search the datafile until you find the match, and if the next character after match is the same as was removed then write a 1 and if not then write a 0, It also needs to search in the most squeezed way possible (from beginning of each character in datafile, not by blocks like normal search in text editor, as portrayed in my previous post: [BASH: Search a string and exactly display the exact number of times a substring happens inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053094/bash-search-a-string-and-exactly-display-the-exact-number-of-times-a-substring)).

Thank you infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY GOT IT DOWN! WOOT!

```
{ 
  # remove spaces
  gsub(/[ ]+/, "", $0)
} 

NR==FNR {
  data=$0;
  data_len = length(data)
  next
} 

{
  pattern = $0
  pattern_len = length(pattern)
  printf("%s\t", pattern)
  for (j=1; j+pattern_len-1 <= data_len; j++) {
    if (substr(data, j, pattern_len-1) ~ substr(pattern, 1, pattern_len-1)) {
      if (substr(data, j + pattern_len - 1, 1) ~ substr(pattern, pattern_len, 1)) {
        result = 1
      }
      else {
        result = 0 
      }
      printf("%s", result) 
    }      
  }
  print ""
}
```